# Get row value corresponding to a column name

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this dataset

```
    Book2 <- structure(list(meanX3 = c(21.66666667, 21.66666667, 11, 25, 240.3333333
), meanX1 = c(23, 34.5, 10, 25, 233.5), meanX2 = c(24.5, 26.5, 
20, 25, 246.5), to_select = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("meanX1", 
"meanX2", "meanX3"), class = "factor"), selected = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("meanX3", "meanX1", "meanX2", "to_select", 
"selected"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

I want to get the coresponding row value for the column name on variable `to_select` .

I have tried

```
Book2 %>%   dplyr::mutate(selected=.[paste0(to_select)])
```

But it returns all the column values. How can I go about to get a data set like

```
structure(list(meanX3 = c(21.66666667, 21.66666667, 11, 25, 240.3333333
), meanX1 = c(23, 34.5, 10, 25, 233.5), meanX2 = c(24.5, 26.5, 
20, 25, 246.5), to_select = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("meanX1", 
"meanX2", "meanX3"), class = "factor"), selected = c(21.66, 34.5, 
20, 25, 240.33)), .Names = c("meanX3", "meanX1", "meanX2", "to_select", 
"selected"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Apart from the answer posts you should notice that you are facing this problem because of untidy data - it would be better to convert to long format imo.

Comment: @docendodiscimus this is just a subset of the data, it has also other variables.The variable `to_select` is created as a result of the mean of the values with a lowest coeficient of variation. I thought it would be dificult to handle the data in a long format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With base R, a safe strategy would be something like

```
cols <- as.character(unique(Book2$to_select))
row_col <- match(Book2$to_select, cols)
idx <- cbind(seq_along(Book2$to_select), row_col)
selected <- Book2[, cols][idx]

Book2$selected <- selected
```

Or using tidyverse packages, something like

```
library(tidyverse)
Book2 %>% mutate(row=1:n()) %>% 
    gather(prop, val, meanX3:meanX2) %>% 
    group_by(row) %>% 
    mutate(selected=val[to_select==prop]) %>%
    spread(prop, val) %>% select(-row)
```

Would be a decent strategy.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to group by row using `rowwise()` and then `get` the value of the string in 'to_select' column

```
Book2 %>% 
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(selected = get(as.character(to_select)))
# A tibble: 5 × 5
#     meanX3 meanX1 meanX2 to_select  selected
#      <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>    <fctr>     <dbl>
#1  21.66667   23.0   24.5    meanX3  21.66667
#2  21.66667   34.5   26.5    meanX1  34.50000
#3  11.00000   10.0   20.0    meanX2  20.00000
#4  25.00000   25.0   25.0    meanX1  25.00000
#5 240.33333  233.5  246.5    meanX1 233.50000
```

Comment: It throws back an error of `Error: object 'meanX3' not found`

Comment: @Keniajin  What is your dplyr version as I am not getting the error based on the example you posted

Comment: I am using `dplyr_0.5.0`

Comment: @Keniajin  I am using the devel version, perhaps that is the difference

Answer (score 2):

In base R you can use `match` to select the desired column and then matrix subsetting to select the particular element for each row like this

```
Book2$selected <- as.numeric(Book2[cbind(seq_len(nrow(Book2)),
                                          match(Book2$to_select, names(Book2)))])
```